# Dynamically and in real time update web page contents

Tags: java, ajax, xml, web, dynamic

I need to create a screen that is automatically updated every minute or so with fresh data from a server-based data source, perhaps a simple text file or XML - and is displayed as a web page.

The screen will show a list of items that can be marked with a red, yellow or green icon, as to indicate their status. Each item has a drop-down where you can select/change the current status. So, when a user changes the status for one of the items, every screen monitoring this web page will be automatically updated.

I'm a pretty novice web programmer (I only have experience with desktop programming, VB and a little C#), so I'm really just hoping for a quick push in the right direction here. I assume that this really isn't all that difficult to implement. Am I wrong? And where can I find more info on how to do this?  :-)

I really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a solution with Websockets. You don't need update every minute. You're able to update every times when a user make changes. Client Side in Java Script is very easily to implement Websockets. Tutorial can be found [here](https://javascript.info/websocket).

Server side you need a Websocket Server. What you need depends on which programm language you use.

Comment: Wow... That was really, really interesting. Thanks a lot. :-)  :-)  I guess I'll be staying up long tonight, hehehe